# Acess violation exception emguCV cvQueryHistValue

Tags: c#, opencv, access-violation, emgucv

I got stuck with Access violation exception in managed code. Histogram pointer is not null and everything seems ok. Got example of creating IntPtr's from http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=59

```
// initializing data
var random = new Random();
var array = new double[1000];
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    array[i] = random.NextDouble();
}
var arrayPtr = GetDataPtr(array);

//initializing ranges array
double[] rangesArray = { 0, 1 };
var rangesArrayPtr = GetRangesArrayPtr(rangesArray);
//creating and querying histogram
var histogramStructure = CvInvoke.cvCreateHist(1, new[] {20}, HIST_TYPE.CV_HIST_ARRAY, rangesArrayPtr, true);
var histogram = CvInvoke.cvMakeHistHeaderForArray(1, new[] { 20 }, histogramStructure, arrayPtr, rangesArrayPtr, 1);
CvInvoke.cvNormalizeHist(histogram, 1.0);
CvInvoke.cvQueryHistValue_1D(histogram, 0); // getting exception here
```

help methods

```
private static IntPtr[] GetRangesArrayPtr(double[] array)
{
    var ranges = new IntPtr[1];
    ranges[0] = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(array.Length * sizeof(double));
    Marshal.Copy(array, 0, ranges[0], array.Length);
    return ranges;
}
private static IntPtr GetDataPtr(double[] array)
{
    var ranges = new IntPtr();
    ranges = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(array.Length * sizeof(double));
    Marshal.Copy(array, 0, ranges,array.Length);
    return ranges;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem in a recent project and solved it by copying the histogram values into a new array.

```
Double[] histtemp = new double[255];

Histogram.MatND.ManagedArray.CopyTo(histtemp,0);
```

Now you can access the histogram values in histtemp. I hope it will help future viewers.